# neo4j shortest path with common relation property

Tags: neo4j, path, cypher, graph-databases, shortest-path

As the picture below shows we have nodes with relations but with different properties. how can I find shortest path between node A and node E with condition that relations in the path should have common property? for example here it only should give THE PATH with property "a" from node A to node B because a here is common.

[image: unique labeled path]

**Edit**
I want to find shortest path between node a and e based on available relations between a and next node (here relation properties are a, b and c) how can I find shortest path between a and e in which relations property is same(here property a)
for example it should return only  the path with property a (and the path would be a>b>d>e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and the answer was:

```
Match (a:node)-[r1]->()
with collect(r1.property) as m
MATCH p=shortestPath( (a:node)-[:r1*]->(e:node) ) 

AND ALL(x in relationships(p) WHERE x.propery in m)
RETURN p
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your property on the relationship is called `filter`, you can define an ALL predicate that will check the all the relationship properties filter in the path have the same value than the first relationship property :

```
MATCH (p1:Node {value: "a"})
MATCH (p2:Node {value: "b"})
MATCH path=shortestPath((p1)-[r*]-(p2))
WHERE ALL( x IN relationships(path) 
      WHERE x.filter = head(relationships(path)).filter
    )
RETURN path
```

Comment: what if the common relation property wasn't the first property maybe the second?
besides database wasn't able to return this query's answer

Comment: @M.B it doesn't matter, since you're saying they should all be the same, so they should be the same on all the rels in the path, also the first one.

Comment: Well, my answer is still correct, since the predicate is on the first relationship, no need to first collect possible values, it will match automatically.

Comment: yours even didn't give back the answer